# JPA: Persisting reused collection items @ManyToMany

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

have a problem with persisting unidirectional @ManyToMany relationship. I'm using EclipseLink 2.3 with Spring data and MySQL.

entities pseudocode:

```
@Entity
public class Subscriber {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<SubscribersList> subscribersLists;

//...shortened...
}

@Entity
public class SubscribersList {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String title;

//...shortened...
}
```

next in some service I create new list and two subscribers...

```
list = new SubscribersList("DEFAULT");
s1 = new Subscriber();
s1.getSubscribersList().add(list); //empty list is created in the constructor
repository.save(s1); //works ok
s2 = new Subscriber();
s2.getSubscribersList().add(list);
repository.save(s2); //fails with Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

after saving the first subscriber, list becomes managed entity, but despite this on saving the second subscriber JPA tries to create list again:

```
Call: INSERT INTO SUBSCRIBERSLIST (ID, DESCRIPTION, TITLE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [2, null, DEFAULT]
```

Interestingly my intergation test with in memory hsqldb works. obviously I'm missing something, but cannot spot the problem...

Answer (score 0):

What does save() do?

The issue is most likely your objects are detched, so never have their id assigned, so nothing related them to the managed objects.

You need to either persist instead of merge them (and ensure you use managed objects not detached).  Or return the id, or perform a find after you save, to ensure you are using a valid object.

Comment: `save()` merges `persist()` and `merge()` with internal logic which determines which to use. I did slight change to my code: removed `CascadeType.PERSIST` from `@ManyToMany`, so need to save the subsribers list first, then set that persisted subscribers list to the newly created subscribers and then persisting of subscribers works.

Comment: so there is probably some misunderstanding on my side how JPA works... I thought, that when I create new object to be persisted, and put to the object graph some already persisted entity (subscribersList in my case), JPA is clever enough to manage it...

Comment: You must not corrupt the objects in your persistence unit.  Any managed object, or new persisted object should only reference other managed objects.  Merge() will resolve things for you, but will return a copy of the detached object that is managed.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Then I'm still curious why my integration tests which use in-memory HSQL works, and MySQL fails. what I mean is that above code works in my test as I mentioned initially...